# List of Objects being Changed when Original Object is Changed

Tags: python

In Python, if I write:

```
a = [1]
b = 3 * [a]
a.append(2)
print a, b
```

Then, the output is:

```
[1, 2] [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

However, when I write:

```
a = [1]
b = 3 * a # notice the missing brackets here 
a.append(2)
print a, b
```

This turns out to be:

```
[1, 2] [1, 1, 1]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, think of what Python does to this statement:

```
b = 3 * [a]
```

It becomes:

```
b = [[a], [a], [a]]
```

Thus, changing `a` will be reflected in `b`, because `b` is constituted of `a` objects.

However, in the second example, you do this:

```
b = 3 * a
```

This creates a copy of list `a`, and is equivalent to:

```
b = [1, 1, 1]
```

Thus, when appending to `a` this time, nothing is changed.

Comment: I understand when we say `b = [a]` , both b and a point to the same references. same is the case when we give `b = a`. So why does it behave differently ONLY when a "*"  operator with an `int` is applied on `a` e.g `b = 3 * a`. could you please explain this as well. TIA

Comment: When you do `b = 3 * a` it creates 3 copies of `a` (in this case `1`), and places them into a list. As for why, I couldn't tell you. I'm sure it has something to do with the language design, but I'm not knowledgable enough about the subject to give a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you do `b = 3 * [a]`, the reference to variable `a` is not lost. Thus, any change made in a will be replicated in b.

However, when you run `b = 3 * a` a new `list` instance is being created, which has no reference to the `a` list anymore.

All data structures in Python are objects, and the variables point to them. :)